# Baire-1 functions properties on a complete metric space $(X, d)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, complete-spaces, borel-sets, baire-category

*Let be $(X, d)$ a complete metric space, $f_n : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a sequence of continuous functions and a function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:*
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} f_n(x)=f(x), \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x \in X$$
*Prove that:*

- *exist and open dense set $W$ of $X$ such that $f$ is locally bounded in $W$*
- *the set $\{ x \in  X :\  f \ continuous\  at\  x\}$ is a $G_\delta$ dense set in $X$.*
  *Can the Dirichlet function at x be the limit of a sequence of continuous functions $f_n \ $ (pointwise convergence)?
  Hence can the derivative of a differentiable function be not continuous in a interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ where its interior is not empty ( $\mathring I \neq \emptyset$)?*

The function $f$ such defined is a Baire-1 function, and I'm required to prove these statements. The exercise suggests to use the fact that: $$X=\bigcup_{k\geq1}\bigcap_{n\geq1}\{|f_n|\leq k\}$$
and repeat the statement on closed-balls inside $X$, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: The pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions is called, usually, a "Baire-one function."   All of this is asking for standard properties of Baire 1 functions.  If you need help search for that topic.   The reason why a derivative $F'$ is a Baire 1 function is because $ n (F(x+\frac1n)-F(x))\to F'(x)$ at each point.

Comment: I managed to find some information about the topic, but I can't find anything about the local bounded property. Any help?